# Can I use get_term_children to show child terms if they exist and show something else if they don't?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a hierarchical custom taxonomy called taxon...  In my taxonomy.php I am showing children of the current taxon, if you click one of those children you should be taken to a page showing all of that child taxon's products.  Parent taxons never have products so its just a navigation structure.

```
    $term_id = $term->term_id; 
    $taxonomyName = "taxons";
    $term_taxons = get_term_children($term_id, $taxonomyName);
    if ($term_taxons != null) { ?>
                Show Child Taxons
            <?php } else { ?>
                SHOW PRODUCTS
            <?php } ?>
```

This does not work.  I have tried running the it like if $term_taxons == null then do something else something else and that doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( ! isset($term_taxons->errors)) { ?>
   Show Child Taxons
<?php } else { ?>
   SHOW PRODUCTS
<?php } ?>
```

get_term_children returns a WP_error on failure.